# KeyListener not triggering actions

Tags: java, swing

The keyListener does not fire action though i registered the frame to the keyListener.
In the other code, implementing the KeyListener interface, registering the JFrame and overriding the appropriate methods was all that was needed for the keyListener to work.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Mains implements KeyListener {
    private static Point point = new Point();

    public Mains() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        JButton button = new JButton("Close Me");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                point.x = e.getX();
                point.y = e.getY();
            }
        });
        frame.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                Point p = frame.getLocation();
                frame.setLocation(p.x + e.getX() - point.x, p.y + e.getY()
                        - point.y);
            }
        });

        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocation(200, 200);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Drag Me", JLabel.CENTER),
                BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Mains();
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("pressed");
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("released");
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

By default, `JFrame` window components are not focusable. Although you *can* call `JFrame.setFocusable(true)`, it is far better to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

`KeyListener` requires focus with components for the interaction with `KeyEvents` to work. In contrast, when using Key Bindings, you can map an Action to a KeyStroke even when a component doesn't have focus.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. well in the other code, there was no where i added the setFocusable(true) method but the code worked just fine, can you enlighten me?

Comment: See update. I would recommend `Key Bindings` for use in Swing though.

Answer (score 4):

A `KeyListerner` is only capable of receiving key events if the component it is attached to can receive focus and has focus.

The problem with a `JFrame` is that it contains a `JRootPane`, which contains a content pane which occupies the entire surface of frame, which will prevent the frame from ever gaining focus, this, never be capable of receiving key events.

`KeyListener` is rarely the right API of choice, normally, it's better to use [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

You may also find [How to use root panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) of interest